# How to launch Gnumeric after installing using Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I've installed [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/) using Homebrew. I first manually installed XQuartz (as required) and then ran `brew install gnumeric`. Everything seems to have installed fine.

Now how do I launch it?

When I run `/usr/local/bin/gnumeric` I see:

```
Cannot open display:
Run '/usr/local/bin/gnumeric --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

This is the result of `/usr/local/bin/gnumeric --help`:

```
Usage:
    /usr/local/bin/gnumeric [OPTION...] [FILE ...]

Help Options:
    -h, --help                                Show help options
    --help-all                                Show all help options
    --help-libspreadsheet                     Show Gnumeric Options
    --help-gtk                                Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
    -g, --geometry=WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF     Specify the size and location of the initial window
    --no-splash                               Don't show splash screen
    --no-warnings                             Don't display warning dialogs when importing
    --display=DISPLAY                         X display to use
```

Comment: Have you tried launching it from an xterm?

Comment: @Édouard Got it! I didn't know I had to launch it using X11. Thanks. If you post an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Without doubt, you will detail the steps you took with more accuracy than I could. I’ll let you post your own, and flag these comments as obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

If you install [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) from [Homebrew Cask](https://caskroom.github.io/) with:

```
brew cask install xquartz
```

and gnumeric from [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) with:

```
brew install gnumeric
```

You can then just type:

```
gnumeric
```

on the command line and the gnumeric window will open.